# What is the best practice for calling stored procedures using the PHP mysqli interface to MariaDB?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, mariadb

I am attempting to port an 8-year-old PHP/MySQL web app to a more recent server stack using MariaDB instead of MySQL.  I have found it impossible to run more than one stored procedure on the same connection due to a "packets out of order" error.  Below is code that should work, but doesn't.  Can someone point out where I may have gone astray here or what would be a successful alternative approach?

```php
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "mysqli_test";
$password = "";
$database = "mysqli_test";

function get_connection()
{
   GLOBAL $host, $user, $password, $database;
   $connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
   if (! $connection || mysqli_connect_errno() )
     printf("Connection failure: %s.\n", mysqli_connect_error());

   return $connection;
}

// Minimum viable function: isolate necessary steps.
function get_person($connection, $first_name)
{
   $query = "CALL Get_By_First_Name(?)";
   if (($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)))  // error here after first pass
   {
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $first_name);
      if ($stmt->execute())
      {
         $stmt->store_result();
         $stmt->bind_result($id, $fname, $lname, $pets);

         while($stmt->fetch())
            printf("%3d %20s %20s %2d.\n", $id, $fname, $lname, $pets);

         $stmt->free_result();
         while ($stmt->next_result())  // my suspected culprit
         {
            $stmt->store_result();
            while ($stmt->fetch())
               ;
            $stmt->free_result();
         }
      }

      $stmt->close();
   }
}

if ($conn = get_connection())
{
   get_person($conn, "Samuel");  // it works the first time
   get_person($conn, "Zelda");   // this time it fails
}

?>
```

Running aPHP/mysqli code,
lmost identical C++ code using the C API works fine, so I can isolate where I think the problem starts: with the next_result() function.  In the C++ code, next_result() returns TRUE to indicate a new result was available after using the prepared statement to run the stored procedure.  In the PHP/mysqli code, next_result() returns false, and, in fact, fails to produce a new result even if I ignore the false return value.

I created a [github repository](https://github.com/cjungmann/mysqli_test.git) that includes more explanation and scripts that can run on your computer to replicate the error, if anyone is interested.

Comment: I have tested the new code after this small change and I can confirm the original problem is gone.

Comment: What versions of PHP and MariaDB are you using?  I'm still getting an Packets out of order error, even with the change to $stmt->next_result().  I also put a print() after the `while ($stmt->next_result())`, which never is called because $stmt->next_result() never returns TRUE (for me).

Comment: PHP 8.0.3 and 10.4.13-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to avoid using stored procedures from PHP... That is not always possible; sometimes stored procedures are necessary and they might even be useful on rare occasions. But if you can, try to move the logic to the PHP application rather than storing it on a MySQL server. It's much less cumbersome this way.

If you want to know how to call stored procedures correctly, the best resource to reach for is the PHP manual. I have recently improved most of the examples in the manual so I know that the examples there reflect best practices and actually work. Read [stored procedures using mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php) and [`mysqli::multi_query()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

I would advise avoiding `mysqli::multi_query()`, despite stored procedures being probably the primary reason that function even exists. You have made the right choice to use prepared statements so you can bind the parameters and avoid SQL injection.

The main thing you have to remember is that `CALL()` statement produces an empty result. If the stored procedure also produces result set/sets then you need to iterate over them and fetch each one. The problem with stored procedures is that you can never be certain how many result sets will be produced. How can you handle the unknown?

Take a look at this example (it's your code but I made some changes and enabled error reporting):

```
function get_connection($host, $user, $password, $database): mysqli
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    return new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    // you might want to set the correct charset (e.g. utf8mb4) here before returning
}

function get_person(mysqli $connection, $first_name): mysqli_result
{
    $query = "CALL Get_By_First_Name(?)";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $first_name);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* We expect this SP to return the main result set,
        which we want to return and then an empty result for CALL.
        Get the result here and return immediately.
        The prepared statement will be closed automatically once
        we leave the scope and this will clean up the remaining result set.
    */
    return $stmt->get_result();
}

$conn = get_connection($host, $user, $password, $database);
$res1 = get_person($conn, "Samuel");
$res2 = get_person($conn, "Zelda");

var_dump($res1->fetch_all(), $res2->fetch_all());
```

In the above code, I make an assumption that the SP I am calling will return only two result sets. I want only the first one and I don't care about the result of `CALL()`. The second result set is discarded when the statement is cleaned up. If that was not the case, I would need to call `mysqli_stmt::next_result()` until all result sets are fetched (not the `mysqli::next_result()`!). **This is the easiest way to handle the cumbersome stored procedures.**

Even if you converted the code to PDO, this would still be the simplest way to do it. With mysqli things can get very complicated if you go over the board though, so be careful not to overengineer the solution. If your stored procedures use cursors, note that there was a bug in PHP up to PHP 7.4.

Comment: Using stored procedures (from PHP or any client), can give you substantial performance benefits and can serve as an abstraction layer between clients and the database (you may have more than one application accessing the database) . You personally may not use stored procedures, but claiming that no one should use them, is not a good advise.

Comment: @slaakso Yes, which is why my second sentence says that they can sometimes be useful. They are still cumbersome to use.

Comment: Was referring your opening line "The best practice is to avoid using stored procedures from PHP ". Again, this is your opinion. When you have your process in order, stored procedures (as any other database feature) are a great benefit. And they are easy to use once you use them (like any other feature the databases offer).

Comment: One reason I use stored procedures is specifically to remove the logic from the PHP files, which may accidentally be revealed.

I have been pretty successful using stored procedures in PHP, so this question is not so much about how to do it (I followed best practices at the time I wrote it, and it worked), but rather to see if others noticed that next_result() seems broken and how they resolved the problem.

Comment: @chuckj If your PHP sensitive code logic is revealed then you're going to have more problems than just the SQL being publicly known. There are valid reasons to use SP and it is possible to call them from PHP. Just be careful when handling multiple results. I also recommend to use PHP 8.1 or at least PHP 8.0. There were a number of bugs fixed in recent releases. `next_result` is not broken and by the looks of it, you don't even need to use it in your code. Can you explain why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: I tried using get_result() instead of store_result() and was surprised that I could get a second result without resolving the first result.  I'm a bit worried about how to handle the extra result each procedure emits, and if ignoring the extra result causes a resource leak.  I also wonder how get_result() sidesteps the problem of incomplete data retrieval that completely thwarts the connection in the other methods.  Does it make a duplicate connection?

Comment: @chuckj I'm a little confused by your statement. There is no resource leak. There is no duplicate connection. `store_result` and `get_result` will buffer the result in PHP, so there's no difference in this regard. The main problem in the code you shared in the question was that you tried to call `mysqli::next_result()` when there were still pending results on the prepared statement. Call `mysqli_stmt::next_result()` to fetch them or discard the prepared statement.

Comment: @Dharman: in the application currently running on PHP 5.3.5, next_result() was necessary to retrieve and dispose of the empty result generated by (as suggested by my recent research) the prepared statement's CALL() command.  Failure to handle that trailing result rendered the connection unusable for subsequent prepared statements.  I get the same error now with PHP 7.3.29 as I did for 5.3.5 for neglecting the next_result(), so I think I still need it.

Comment: @Dharman: As far as next_result() being broken, my evidence is that next_result() doesn't return TRUE, even though I know there's an uncollected result.  Tracing through similar C API code, next_result() returns TRUE, I can handle the extra result, and the connection is then ready for another prepared statement/stored procedure call.  Are you using next_result() in your code somewhere, that you can confirm it's not broken?  If so, maybe my problem is a version problem rather than a problem with my PHP code.

Comment: @Dharman: I tried several versions of next_result(), mysqli_stmt_next_result($stmt), $stmt->next_result(), etc.  In all cases, next_result() returns nothing.  I don't know if it's returning void or NULL or FALSE, but it never returns TRUE.  In C API, it returns 0 for failure, non-zero for success (I think it's 1, but I'm not certain right now), and I get 1 when I expect it.  And I've changed my code to use $stmt->next_result() in case you're right about that problem, I just haven't changed the original post.

Comment: As I said, your code would work if you used the right function. Use `mysqli_stmt::next_result()` rather than `mysqli:next_result()`. Looks at example #4 https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: store_result() and get_result() have different outcomes.  After your original comment, I testing using get_result() and it allows the program to call prepare_statement() immediately, even though I have to assume that the empty result is still hanging.  I don't claim there's a resource leak or extra connection, I'm just speculating about how get_result() avoids the problems that occur when using store_result().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237648/discussion-between-dharman-and-chuckj).